# USB camera /dev/video0 and TV card /dev/video1 are mixing

Tags: webcam, tv-tuner

Sometimes when I start the system my web camera is set on /dev/video0, and sometimes it's on /dev/video1 and the TVtuner is on /dev/video0. 
I'd like to set it consistently, that one device is always on /dev/video0 and other /dev/video1, not that they interchange if I disconnect the USB or randomly on system start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a persistent udev rule, in /etc/udev/

See /lib/udev/rules.d for help on how to configure the specific rule.

I am not sure how the rule should exactly look like, however it should be similar to these network rules:

```
# PCI device 0x8086:0x1242 (iwlagn)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:12:ab:52:44:36",
  ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

which says that if the hardware address of the device is 00:12:ab:52:44:36, then it should use the name `wlan0`.

**UPDATE:** See http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html and http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/ for instructions.

Comment: Is there somewhere a comprehensive manual for this?